# Scope changes from inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm using BreezeJS with AngularJS but I'm having a difficult time understanding how to get Promises to work with $scope. Whenever I try to submit my form its not showing the validation errors until I click it for a 2nd time. I realize I could call $scope.$apply() but I read its not best practice? Here is my code:

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$q", "datacontext", function ($scope, $q, datacontext) {
    datacontext.manager.fetchMetadata();
    $scope.errors = [];

    $scope.addDamp = function () {
        var item = datacontext.manager.createEntity("Damp", {
            name: $scope.newDamp
        });

        var tes = datacontext.manager.saveChanges()
            .then(function () {
                alert("yay");
            })
            .fail(function (error, a, b, c) {
                var arr = [];
                error.entitiesWithErrors.map(function (entity) {
                    entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().map(function (validationError) {
                        arr.push(validationError.errorMessage);
                    });
                });
                $scope.errors = arr;
                datacontext.manager.rejectChanges();
            });
    };
}]);
```

What is the best way to go about handling scope changes that come from inside of a Promise?

Comment: It's only 'not best practice' to use `$scope.$apply()` where it's not needed ... but this is exactly the sort of situation it was intended for. http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're going to need $scope.apply here, because the promise isn't coming out of a core Angular call (such as $http, which would have handled the .apply() itself behind the scenes). In fact, the Breeze/Angular example on the BreezeJS page (http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-angular) includes a $scope.apply() after its data retrieval:

```
   datacontext.getAllTodos()
              .then(success)
              .fail(failed)
              .fin(refreshView); 

  function refreshView() {
      $scope.$apply();
  }
```

It's a bad practice to toss $scope.apply() about where you don't need it. But when you're handling promises created outside of Angular itself, it's going to come up.